# Are there any easy-to-understand and working tutorials for JBox2D?

Tags: java, android, collision-detection, game-physics, jbox2d

I am looking for some beginner tutorials for the newest release of JBox2D. The ones I have found are all outdated. If possible a tutorial on how to apply the whole thing on android would also be good. I am simply trying to make some walls that the player cant go through and apply some gravity.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hмм, the first google result seems useful:

http://www.4feets.com/2009/03/2d-physics-on-android-using-box2d/

However, if you know c++ or actionscript a little, you can successfully use tutorials for these languages. Box2d code in c++ and actionscript is quite similar to Java code.
So you can try to learn these tutorials written in c++:

http://www.kerp.net/box2d/

Answer (score 3):

you can find JBox2D tutorials for beginners [here](http://thisiswhatiknowabout.blogspot.com/search/label/JBox2D%20Tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to learn how to work with the physics engine, please look at the wiki [here](http://code.google.com/p/jbox2d/wiki), specifically at the [Testbed](http://code.google.com/p/jbox2d/wiki/Testbed) page.  The testbed provides everything you need to run the engine so you only have to work with the physics code itself.